# Overriding setIcon() method in setUI(new BasicComboBOxUI){}

Tags: java, overriding, jcombobox

I have to set the custom image in my dropdown for JComboBox. I was quite successful to remove it (by overriding getWidth()) but I am not able to replace arrow with my custom image. Here is my code snippet to get better idea. I don't know where I am doing wrong but its showing some elevated portion at button section.

```
    cmbYear = new JComboBox();
    cmbYear.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI(){
        protected JButton createArrowButton() {
            return new JButton() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                public void setIcon(Icon defaultIcon) {
                    defaultIcon = new ImageIcon("images/dropdown_icon.png");
                    super.setIcon(defaultIcon);
                }
   //           public int getWidth() {
   //                return 0;
   //            }
            };
        }
    });
```

Please help me here. Thank you very much for you time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override getIcon instead. Cache icon as needed.

```
@Override
public Icon getIcon() {
  Icon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/dropdown_icon.png"));
  return defaultIcon;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help. Its working perfectly now for following.

 Icon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon("images/dropdown_icon.png");

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I was loading the icon from the package path.